# How to call validate method of Element-UI form

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying design some forms with [Element-UI](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form) in one of my Vue.js projects. I want to check if the form is valid before continuing any further action once the submit button is clicked.

Can anybody direct me to an example how to reference the element inside a Vue component and check its validity.

Following is my form setup.

```
 <div id="frmEventCreate">
 <el-form v-bind:model="data" v-bind:rules="rules">
    <el-form-item label="Event name" prop="name" required>
       <el-input v-model="data.name"></el-input>
    </el-form-item>

    <el-button type="success" v-on:click="next" icon="el-icon-arrow-right"> Next Step </el-button>
 </el-form>
 </div>

var objEvent = {neme: "Some Name"};
vmEventCreate = new Vue({
    el: '#frmEventCreate',
    data: {
        data: objEvent,
        rules: {
            name: [
                {required: true, message: 'Please input event name', trigger: 'blur'},
                {min: 10, max: 100, message: 'Length should be 10 to 100', trigger: 'blur'}
            ]
        },
    },
    methods: {
        next: function () {
            // need to check if the form is valid, here..
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form#validation) is the link to the validation example in Element UI docs

You need to add a ref attribute to your form like this:

```
 <el-form v-bind:model="data" v-bind:rules="rules" ref="someForm">
```

Then, when you click on the submit button which is calling the **`next`** method in your case you can validate your form like this:

```
this.$refs['someForm'].validate((valid) => {
  if (valid) {
    alert('submit!');
  } else {
    console.log('error submit!!');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes figured out this `ref` thing and fixed it the way you have suggested in your answer.

Comment: Follow-up question: is there a way to limit the validation to triggering only when submit button is clicked? 
From the examples it seems like it also automatically validates on blur as well. If I don't want that, how do I suppress it?

Comment: @lukkyjoe you can try and use the validate-on-rule-change attribute on form tag. More info here: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form#form-attributes